# @Ejb annotation In Servlet filter Fails with no such bean

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I am trying to inject an EJB stateless bean in to a servlet Filter, but the servlet throws a NullPointerExcetion with below error:

```
Dependency injection failure: can't find the bean definition about 
class interface com.bofa.gcib.ccp.customer.ejb.remote.AuditRemote; 
nested exception is    
com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.beans.factory.
NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No unique bean of type
```

AuditRemote is an interface which is implemented by AuditEJB.

```
@Remote(AuditRemote.class)
@Stateless(name = "AuditEJB", mappedName = "AuditEJB", description = "Audit  Bean")
@Interceptors(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.class)
public class AuditEJB implements AuditRemote {

}
```

Trying to inject this EJB into Servlet Filter as below.

```
@Stateless

public class CustomFilter implements Filter {

 @EJB(mappedName = "AuditEJB")
    private AuditEJB  auditEJB;

}
```

Comment: try (at)Autowired instead of (at)EJB

Comment: Nope..it did not work.. getting Nullpointer Exception now.

Comment: ok, try (at)ManagedBean  on the filter

Comment: @ManagedBean also does not work. I am not using JSF for implementation